# Compute variable with wildcard on variable names in SPSS?

Tags: variables, wildcard, spss

I have a dataset with variables that start with category 'RC' and end wih a number that corresponds to a brand. The middle letter refers to a product.

For example:
RC_x_1 RC_b_1 RC_g_1 RC_x_2 RC_b_2 RC_g_2 etc.

Each variable has 5 values. I want to compute a new variable with all variables per brand that score within top 2 values.

So:
RC_x_1 (1 or 2) OR RC_b_1 (1 or 2) OR RC_g_1 (1 or 2) = RC_all_1
RC_x_2 (1 or 2) OR RC_b_2 (1 or 2) OR RC_g_2 (1 or 2) = RC_all_2

I tried some wild card options like:
If RC_"*"*1 = 1 OR RC*"*"_1 = 2 RC_all_1 =1.

But it doesn't work :) Any ideas how to create something like this?

Thanks mucho!

Comment: You need to use `spssinc select variables` command (look it up) which enables selecting variables using wildcards. See examples in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996321/loop-for-automated-formatting-of-variables-in-spss/67997256#67997256) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461075/selecting-variables-based-on-partial-names/54464676#54464676)